# How do I draw various shapes in Java ? Which library should I use?

Tags: java, swing, drawing, shapes

I want to write a program which can draw any type of shape that I assign to it like

1. Circle
2. Square
3. Rectangle

Which library should I use , and how do I go about it in Java ?

I am a python coder , thus finding it difficult to cope with Java .

Answer (score 8):

Sure you can do that using Swing. You may want to look into Java's [Shape](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Shape.html) library for that.

Alternatively you can simply override the Component's paint method as shown below.

[image]

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class ShapeTest extends JFrame{
     public ShapeTest(){
          setSize(400,400);
          setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
          setLocationRelativeTo(null);
          setVisible(true);
     }

     public static void main(String a[]){
         new ShapeTest();
     }

     public void paint(Graphics g){
          g.drawOval(40, 40, 60, 60); //FOR CIRCLE
          g.drawRect(80, 30, 200, 200); // FOR SQUARE
          g.drawRect(200, 100, 100, 200); // FOR RECT
     }
}
```

Comment: so which one would be better? 2d api or shape library ?

Comment: the shape library (Java2d) is the comprehensive one. if you are just going to display or play with drawing in java, then overridding the paint() method is enough. if you could tell me your purpose, i can guide you ..

Comment: excellent . I just want a box in which I will click mark on a particular type of image from a check box , and the image will appear . If I click reset , it will disappear and give me a black screen .

Comment: If this is as simple as you've told, then overriding the paint() method is more than enough. Its very straight forward. You will have to add a listener to the checkbox and write the logic in paint() method to handle the condition on what to do when.

Comment: -1, You should never override the paint() method of a JFrame, especially when you don'tinvoke supper.paint(). Custom painting is done by overriding the paintComponent() method of a Swing component like JPanel. Also you should always invoke super.paintComponent(). Read the section from the Swing tutorial on Custom Painting (http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for more information and examples.

Comment: I am having problems in coding a box inside which the shapes would appear . And when I click reset a black screen will be formed .

Comment: Is that the last supper.paint()? [\humor]

Answer (score 4):

The [Java2D](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/) API has what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [Custom Painting Approaches](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/) for a couple of ideas. The DrawOnComponent is closer to what you want. It would need to be changed to add your custom shape objects to the list.

Answer (score 2):

[`GraphPanel`](https://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/graphpanel) is a simple example of an object drawing program that features moveable, resizable, colored nodes connected by edges.

Answer (score 0):

*Java 2D* is what you neede  drawing graphics (i.e., draw colored rectangles, circles, lines, and animate them).