# How to create graphics using JFrame form?

Tags: java, netbeans

I want to know how to create graphics (draw shapes, move shapes) by using the JFrame form in NetBeans. I have already watched the tutorials in youtube, about how to create shapes and move them. But all the tutorials are done in normal java class file. I want to know how to do it on a JFrame Form (The java class file that you can edit the interface of JFrame visually) like in this image http://image.ohozaa.com/i/b84/mOu1ku.png
I try to do the code similar to the tutorial but it isn't work

Ball.java

```
public class Ball extends JPanel{
int x = 0;
int y = 0;

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D gra = (Graphics2D) g;
    gra.setColor(Color.red);
    gra.fillOval(x, y, 50, 50);
    x++;
    y++;
    repaint();
}
```

Interface.java

```
private void DrawButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    Ball ball1 = new Ball();
    animationPanel.add(ball1);
}
```

Main class

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Interface f = new Interface();
    f.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: related [How do I draw various shapes in Java ? Which library should I use?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4578835/how-do-i-draw-various-shapes-in-java-which-library-should-i-use)

Comment: state claerly and shortly, what do you want to do?